# AngularJS UI-Router Change States Of Dependent Modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I am exploring different configuration options for my app. My main goal is to find a way to configure the states/routes on the highest level even if dependent angular modules have their own routes/states declared. There are several options I have come up with but I'm not sure if they are possible or not:

Assume I have module1 which is dependent on module2

1: If module2 declares its own states/routes, is there a way I can delete or override them from module1?

2: Is there a way I can get a list of recommended states (objects that represent states such as `{name: 'state', templateURL: '/someURL'}` and use module1 to logically determine which stateObjects to give the $stateProvider?

3: Is it possible to access the stateProvider NOT in the config? For example, say I have the following that gets setup in the config:

```
tinkModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'templates/create.html'
    });
    $stateProvider.state("otherwise", {
        url: "/otherwise",
        templateUrl: 'templates/tinkOtherwise.html'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise');
});
```

Can I add a 'review' state after they have been through the create state?

Please let me know if there are other options that I am not thinking about and also let me know if any of the above is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your main goal is to define states across modules and also lazy load states. There is some existing features to accomplish these.

Register states across various modules:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-ui-router-from-multiple-modules

You'll need to build 0.3.0 manually with grunt though: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#developing

Then if you want to lazy load (define states on-the-fly) you can read about the $stateNotFound event: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

And look at the ui-router test for lazy loading: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/test/stateSpec.js#L196-L208

The test shows how you might try to `go` to an undefined state, get the $stateNotFound error, which allows you to define the missing state at that time. It will always try once more to find the state, assuming that you may have defined it in the error callback.

Comment: That is essentially what I'm looking for. Looking through the test they create a local var for the stateProvider so they can lazy load stuff. How can I get access to the stateProvider in my app outside of the config?

Comment: And where can I see the differences between 0.2.0 and 0.3.0?

Comment: Sorry, I am only now getting back to you! So there isn't really a reliable changelog yet to see the difference from 0.2.0 to 0.3.0, we are working on adding a changelog soon.

Comment: So in the config you would store a reference to stateProvider into a global var or perhaps a module.value object.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me but I already figured it out. I ended up using a constant.